# Is there a way for CONNECT-PG-SIMPLE to automatically remove expired sessions in DB?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, passport.js, prisma

I am trying to fully understand the authentication flow for **Node/Express, PasspostJS, and Postgres** from a basic side-project. Logging in from the App creates a cookie that expires in 1 day in the client and in the Session table from the store/db. Logging out deletes the cookie from the client and also delete the session from the store/db. Now the problems are:

1. When the cookie is expired, the store/db continues to store it? Is this how it's supposed to work?
2. And then when I log in with the same user, a new session is created. Is there a way to overwrite the previously expired session? Or is it ok to leave the expired sessions there?

I am using **connect-pg-simple** as a store. I have an endpoint that checks if the reques from the client is authenticated => /persist => `authRouter.get('/persist', isAuthenticated, authUser)`.

My session config via **express-session** and connect-pg-simple for store.

```
app.use(
  session({
    store: store,
    secret: SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false,
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'none' : 'lax',
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    },
  }),
);
```

This is my Prisma schema for Session.

```
model session {
  sid    String   @id @db.VarChar
  sess   Json     @db.Json
  expire DateTime @db.Timestamp(6)

  @@index([expire], map: "IDX_session_expire")
}
```

I have read about the **rolling** property, but I am not sure if it's what I need.